# Clojure: Extract maps with specific values from Lazy Sequence

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

I have a Clojure Lazy Sequence:

```
{
    {:keyOne 123, :keyTwo "TestVal"}
    {:keyOne 456, :keyTwo "Value2"}
    {:keyOne 789, :keyTwo "TestVal"}
}
```

I want to get the maps which have a specific value for a given key, e.g. I want all maps which have the value `"TestVal"` as the `:keyTwo` value, so I'd expect the first and third element in my result.

I assume I should be able to solve this using `filter`, but I've looked through all examples I could find and they never use such a nested structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{{:keyOne 123, :keyTwo "TestVal"}
 {:keyOne 456, :keyTwo "Value2"}
 {:keyOne 789, :keyTwo "TestVal"}}
```

In clojure, this expression doesn't make sense, this isn't the lazy sequence of maps.
To answer your question adequately,I think input data is like as below:

```
(def input '({:keyOne 123, :keyTwo "TestVal"}
             {:keyOne 456, :keyTwo "Value2"}
             {:keyOne 789, :keyTwo "TestVal"}))
```

We can make the expression for your purpose like this:

```
(filter (fn [m] (= "TestVal" (:keyTwo m))) input)
```

It doesn't care whether the input sequence is lazy or not-lazy(eager).

Comment: `map identity` is very strange. There is no need to force the input to be lazy: anything that works for lazy sequences should work for eager sequences, including the code you have written.

Comment: Your comment is exact. It is meaningless to treat eager sequence as lazy seq. I will modify my answer more practical and accurate.